# how to use laravel on main page - from a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel

I decide to use Laravel on my existing blog - let's say - `example.com`
All of my files and folders are inside `public_html` folder
I installed `Laravel` using `Softaculous` on `cPanel`
Firstly I tried to install it inside `public_html` - but get a warning - `index.php already exists`
So I choose `public_html/lar/` as destination
and now - how can I use the framework on my site ?
for example on my home page (`index.php`) I have an ajax call to `index.pro.php`
let's say - `index.pro.php` need to send an email
how can I use Laravel engine for that task ?
it is installed completelly on a differrent folder - i.e. subfolder - `public_html/lar/` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your .htaccess file on cPanel

```
DirectoryIndex public_html/lar/public/index.php
```

Comment: does it mean - I need to move all my files and folders from `public_html` to `public_html/lar/public/` ?

Comment: No, you just need to edit .htaccess file

Comment: I did, and now entering the `example.com` I'm getting the list of files and folders of my site - inside `public_html`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).